# How to check if the deployment synchronizer in WSO2 is committing to svn?

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-iot

I have a set of four clustered WSO2 EMM instances, 2 management and 2 worker nodes. These are all separate virtual machines. All nodes have joined the cluster succesfully through multicast. The database is also on a remote VM. Deployment synchronizer is activated and configured on all the nodes; they should commit to an SVN remote VM.

The SVN server is correctly configured, because it accepts commits from another test VM.

Normally the manager nodes should commit the contents of /repository/deployment/server to the SVN server.

Shouldn't these commits be happening automatically?
More important at the moment, can I force a manual commit just to check that everything is set up correctly?
(I don't see anything happening in the logs, and the contents of the SVN repository doesn't change either...)

FYI, this is a snippet from carbon.xml:

```
 <DeploymentSynchronizer>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <AutoCommit>true</AutoCommit>
        <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
        <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
        <SvnUrl>http://10.1.0.18/emm</SvnUrl>
        <SvnUser>{{ username }}</SvnUser>
        <SvnPassword>{{ password }}</SvnPassword>
        <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>true</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
    </DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

Answer (score 1):

These commits should be happening automatically from the manager node and worker nodes should be automatically checking out the updates. After you start up the manager node, if you see a folder created at SVN repo named '-1234' then it has committed the content in '/repository/deployment/server'. Until you do any change in this folder there won't be any update from worker node. 
If still issues exist, it will be good idea to check the connection to the SVN repo.

Comment: I'll have to look into that. Somewhat related, should all nodes have the same content from the start? Or only one manager node (or both)?